# Disable of checkbox and text

Tags: javascript, jsp, checkbox

listItem.eid is an id, the text gets populated based on this id.If the listItem.eid gets  id's of 10 , 11 and 12 then the checkbox and text both should be disabled and also greyout the text.

But the one i tried (shown below) removes the checkbox and text instead of disable the text and checkbox.is there any way to do it?

```
<c:if test="${(listItem.eid == '10') && (listItem.eid == '11') &&  (listItem.eid == '12') }">
<td>
<input type="checkbox" class="disabled" name="titleDisplay" value='<c:out value="${listItem.eid}"/>' 
<c:out value="${listItem.checkedStatus == 'Disabled'}"/> />
```

Exact code:

```
<style>
  .disabled {
    color:#808080;
  }
</style>
```

then

```
  <c:if test="${!empty MODE.model.roleList}">
    <c:forEach var="roleGroupItem" items="${MODE.model.roleList}">
        <c:forEach var="listItem" items="${roleGroupItem.entitlments}">
            <c:if test="${listItem.group == 'STPL'}">
                <tr class="<%=getRowOddEven()%>">
                <c:if test="${(listItem.eid == '10') && (listItem.eid == '11') &&  (listItem.eid == '12') }">
                <td>
                <input type="checkbox" class="disabled" name="titleDisplay" value='<c:out value="${listItem.eid}"/>' 
                <c:out value="${listItem.checkedStatus == 'Disabled'}"/> />
                </td>
                </c:if>

                <c:if test="${(listItem.eid != '10') && (listItem.eid != '11') && (listItem.eid != '12') }">
                            <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="titleDisplay" value='<c:out value="${listItem.eid}"/>' <c:out value="${listItem.checkedStatus}"/>> 
                            <%if(key == null) {} else {%><c:out  value="${listItem.checkedStatus}"/> <%}%> 
                            <c:if test="${!empty MODE.errMsg}">
                                 <c:out value="${listItem.checkedStatus}"/>
                            </c:if>
                            <c:out value="${listItem.name}" />
                            </td>       
                            </c:if>
                </tr>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Any of your help is really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of below code:

```
<c:if test="${(listItem.eid == '10') && (listItem.eid == '11') &&  (listItem.eid == '12') }">
 <td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="disabled" name="titleDisplay" value='<c:out value="${listItem.eid}"/>' 
   <c:out value="${listItem.checkedStatus == 'Disabled'}"/> />
 </td>
</c:if>
```

Use the following code:

```
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" <c:if test="${(listItem.eid == '10') || (listItem.eid == '11') ||  (listItem.eid == '12') }"> class="disabled" </c:if> name="titleDisplay" value='<c:out value="${listItem.eid}"/>' 
    <c:out value="${listItem.checkedStatus == 'Disabled'}"/> />
  </td>
```

First you are using `&&` condition and at the one time the value of `listItem.eid` can be either 10 or 11 or 12. so you need to change condition `&&` to `||`.

Comment: oh no... i think i have gone blind for && and ||... Thanks much for saving me :)

Answer (score 1):

"(listItem.eid == '10') && (listItem.eid == '11') &&  (listItem.eid == '12')" is probably the origin of your problem.
Shouldn't you do something like that, instead ?

```
<c:if test="${(listItem.eid == '10') || (listItem.eid == '11') ||  (listItem.eid == '12') }">
            <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="disabled" name="titleDisplay" value='<c:out value="${listItem.eid}"/>' 
            <c:out value="${listItem.checkedStatus == 'Disabled'}"/> />
```

Otherwise, you never go inside the if and the checkboxes don't appear.

EDIT : oops ! Too late ! I agree with code-lღver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<textarea id="d">vdxc</textarea>
<input type="radio" id="d" value="lol">
<input type="button" onclick="lol()" value="fgdrs">
<script type="JavaScript">
function lol()
{
document.getElementById("d").disabled="true";
}
</script>
```